# JMeter Issue during generating HTML report

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I've wrote tests few days back and they worked without problem.

Now when I try to run them, they exit with code 1 and error message:

> An error occurred: null

I'm running it on **TeamCity**

.jtl file is created with no problem.

Here is fragment of log from run.

```
[17:03:02][Step 2/2] jmeter args=-g tests/report/dynamic-checkout.jtl -o tests/report/dynamic-checkout
[17:03:03][Step 2/2] Dec 05, 2019 4:03:03 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
[17:03:03][Step 2/2] INFO: Created user preferences directory.
[17:03:03][Step 2/2] An error occurred: null
[17:03:03][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 1
[17:03:03][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 1 (Step: Performance Tests Execution (Command Line))
[17:03:03][Step 2/2] Step Performance Tests Execution (Command Line) failed
```

I've tried to find solution, but I've just found few articles that are about java version.
Solution provided in other issue on stackoverflow:

> alternatives --config java

When I tried to use this, **TeamCity** shows me, there is only 1 java version and that is selected.

**EDIT:**
I've just found out, that even the test itself run for 0 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Error message is very generic, be helpful if there was more to go on. If you are open to try this out, I'd recommend you try and use blazemeter taurus and see if it can run your test, taurus automatically install all plugins and dependencies.

So if your issue is caused by a missing plugin then this should fix it.

Comment: I was more looking into it, and there is possibly problem with using CSV Data Set. 
( when i disabled it, and used static data, it worked with no problem. )

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) you're not running the tests, you're trying to [generate a HTML reporting dashboard out of the existing .jtl results file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only).

Most probably you're getting the error because your `tests/report/dynamic-checkout.jtl` is empty, double check that it is present, not empty and its content matches [Result File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) properties

The reasons for previous JMeter test failure or dashboard generation failure normally should be reflected in [*jmeter.log* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/).

Comment: Exactly, my test result ( .jtl ) is empty. But why ? Why is .jtl empty ( when i try to run it on local, it works )

Comment: It might be the case the test fails on the remote slaves, there could be different reasons for this, for example: if you use external CSV files for parameterization - you need to manually copy them to the slaves, if you use JMeter plugins - you need to install the plugins on the slaves. Firewall can block sending results from slaves to master, etc. Inspect *jmeter-server.log* files on remote slaves for any clues. See [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/) for more details.